# FileSystemObject CopyFile with wildcard copies files with extensions longer than specified

Tags: vb6, fso

In the source folder there are 3 files:

- `a.csv`
- `b.csv`
- `a.csv_backup`

I would expect `*.csv` to copy `a.csv` and `b.csv` only, but it copies `a.csv_backup` as well.

Code:

```
Dim oFso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
oFso.CopyFile "c:\temp\*.csv" "d:\temp\"
```

Answer (score 4):

You're running into the fact that each file has a "short name" (the old DOS 8.3 standard) for compatibility with really old software (some of which is still kicking around). Your file `a.csv_backup` is also known by another name (probably something like `a~1.csv` though it could be about anything) which only uses the first three letters of the extension. You can run `dir /x` to see the short names alongside each long name.

Further reading:

- On Superuser: [Windows wildcards with files having more than 3 characters extensions](https://superuser.com/q/825615/169501)
- From Raymond Chen (Developer who has worked on Windows for a very long time): [Why does FindFirstFile find short names?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050720-16/?p=34883/) (about the API used internally by many applications to look for files by pattern)
- Wikipedia: [8.3 filename](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename)

In terms of a solution, you either need your backup extension to not share the first three characters of what you're searching for (so use something like `.backup_csv` instead), or you need to [disable short names](https://serverfault.com/questions/293803/how-to-disable-short-path-alias-generation-in-windows) on your system (which can break old applications).